# Installing Apache, PHP, MySql and phpMyAdmin on MacOS

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, webserver

I recently got my MacBook Pro and I tried to install a complete web server on my MacBook until I realized it wasn't working. I created an index.php file to run phpinfo(); it's not working. Later I also realized that mysql was not working either. I tried installing mysql using the dmg file from the website but still no result. I tried following some youtube videos and online resources but still nothing. And as of Apache, not sure what's going on. It just loads the index.html file that says "It's working". I removed that file from Sites and also from /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html. I also tried using XAMPP.

I followed the following links:
Youtube - [Click here for the Youtube video I followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-O8reYBPwRc).

Medium - [Click here for the Medium article I followed](https://medium.com/better-programming/install-apache-mysql-php-macos-mojave-10-14-b6b5c00b7de).

[Another Article I followed from another website.](https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-macos-homebrew/)

I couldn't find much on Google so had to come here and would like to know what I can do to get them up and running.

My System:
MacBook Pro 15 2018
MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in XAMPP where did you create your index.php ? and in browser what is the output when you call index.php ? and which version of XAMPP did you install, and is it vm ?

Comment: @MohdAlomar hi, htdocs folder. in browser it just says "It's working!", like I mentioned earlier. I googled XAMPP and downloaded the latest version for OS X, and it was not the VM one.

Comment: xampp default page is xampp dashboard, you have two web servers which will make collision, remove apache and mysql that you installed manually and then use XAMPP

Comment: I tried. still nothing